# MySQL GROUP BY - get items in that particular group

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the MySQL GROUP BY function, and want to know if there is a way to get the number of items for that group without having to a query again?

```
$homePointsPlayerResult = mysql_query("SELECT `player_id` FROM `conversions` WHERE `game_id` = '$game_id' AND `team_id` IS NULL GROUP BY `player_id`");

while ($players_with_points_conversions[] = mysql_fetch_row($homePointsPlayerResult)) {
    if (array_search($players_with_points_conversions['player_id'],$home_players,true) == FALSE) {
        $home_players['player_id'] = $players_with_points_conversions['player_id'];
        $home_players['conversions'] = {WANT NUMBER OF ELEMENTS FOR THIS GROUP};
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate your answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html):

```
SELECT `player_id`, COUNT(*) AS conversions FROM `conversions` WHERE `game_id` = '$game_id' AND `team_id` IS NULL GROUP BY `player_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another column to the SELECT list along the lines of:   "count(player_id) AS elementCount"